# Apache 2.4 Require all denied not working with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I'm having a weird problem since upgrading to Apache 2.4. It appears that the RewriteRule is overriding the parts of the .htaccess file's deny all command.

```
Require all denied

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index\.php\/(.*) /$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What happens is any individual files, like /robots.txt or /favicon.ico get the appropriate 403 error. However, when trying to render part of the website like /site/login it actually allows the browser through and the server executes index.php and renders the login form (albeit with no JS or CSS since all those assets are 403s)

I'm not an expert here, but it seems like the "Require all denied" part should end the execution. Why is it still allowing execution of index.php?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this problem. Is `/site/` a real directory and does it have another .htaccess?

Comment: /site/ is not a real directory. This is a custom code implementation with Yii, so all non-real file requests get routed to index.php to decide what to do with them